# Getting data from Blazor Monaco editor fails/timeout if there is a lot of data

Tags: c#, blazor, monaco-editor

I am using a Blazor app with the Monaco editor. I use the `SetValue()` and `GetValue()` methods to write and read the content of the editor, which is working fine in most cases.

However, if there is a lot of data in there, then Blazor gets a timeout when `GetValue()` is called. I am reading in a JSON file, so I could remove some lines, and at some point, it is working fine again.

This is the code I am using to read the content of the editor:

```cs
string userRequirementsJson = await UserRequirementsEditor.GetValue();
```

The data that is in the editor is pasted below. It goes on for about 2000 lines, so I removed most of it.

```json
[{
    "feature": "<redacted>",
    "path": [],
    "priority": 9999
}, {
    "feature": "<redacted>",
    "path": [],
    "priority": 9998
}, 

...

, {
    "feature": "<redacted>",
    "path": [],
    "priority": 9996
}, {
    "feature": "<redacted>",
    "path": ["<redacted>", "<redacted>"],
    "priority": 9999
}]
```

Does anyone know why it is possible to read around 1000 lines, but not 2000? And how can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing the same issue, I manage to solve it by increasing SignalR Message size.

```cs
builder.Services.AddSignalR(e =>
{
    e.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 102400000;
});
```